# ShellExecute not working c++

Tags: winapi

I'm trying to use ShellExecute but it just doesn't want to work. I tried a lot of stuff from other forums but i haven't find a suitable solution as i dont want to use System()!

Here is the part of my code :

```
void myClass::executeWMP()
{
    ShellExecute(???);
    cout << "\n";
}
```

For the beginning i want to execute the Windows Media Player from the Path :

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Media Player\wmplayer.exe"

And then could someone please explain the parameters of the function?

*I use Windows 7

Comment: i am sorry for my bad grammar, my first language is not english!

Comment: okay : so I try to use this : ShellExecute(HWND hwnd,LPCTSTR lpOperation,LPCTSTR lpFile,LPCTSTR lpParameters,LPCTSTR lpDirectory,nShowCmd); but i don't know how i can put in the path, and where. And i don't really understand why i need this six parameters.

Comment: The documentation explains the parameters. You should read that.

Comment: @drescherjm yes, I will try to write a more clear question next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I take it your referring to shell execute from the windows library:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153(v=vs.85).aspx

```
ShellExecute(nullptr,L"open",L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Media Player\\wmplayer.exe",nullptr,nullptr,SW_SHOW)
```

The first parameter is the window handle, can be null.

The second parameter is the operation to perform on the file.

The third parameter refer to the file.

The fourth parameter refer to what working directory to change to when opening the file, can be null.

The fifth parameter refers to in what mode to open the file/program in.

Comment: thanks! It works. but if I type in "open" for the second paramter, the compiler says that the type is incompatible?

Comment: @HansPeter Read the error message. It says a lot more than that. It says that the function expects LPCWSTR but you are passing `char*`. So do what it says. Pass a wide string: `L"open"`. If you don't know about narrow and wide strings, stop what you are doing and learn about them. Finally, don't use `ShellExecute`. Use `CreateProcess`.

Comment: I see. @David Heffernan yes I think i'll have to take a look at narrow and wide strings and try CreateProcess, thanks!

Comment: Don't forget to initialize COM on the calling thread prior to calling `ShellExecute`. Or don't use `ShellExecute` altogether. `CreateProcess` is more appropriate here.

Comment: You should almost always pass `NULL` instead of `"open"` for the verb.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run a particular executable file, without regard for file associations in the registry, then you should use `CreateProcess`, not `ShellExecute`.

```
LPCWSTR app = L"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Windows Media Player\\wmplayer.exe";
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof si };
CreateProcessW(app, app, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
Closehandle(pi.hThread);
```

Comment: This is correct. Of course, there are even more parameters in `CreateProcess` than `ShellExecute`. And handles to close. If he can't call `ShellExecute`, little hope of calling `CreateProcess`. The one exception to your statement is when you need to force elevation with the `runas` verb.

Comment: thanks, I saw this function too, but the solution of David Kron is working for me!

Comment: @Hans The solution [proposed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20455518/1889329) by David Kron is of the *Works on my Machine* kind. It may or may not work on someone else's machine, and it may stop working on yours at some point in the future. This answer is a better match for your question.